# How to install a system wide self signed certificate in android?

Tags: android

I am creating an MFA app that needs to store a unique certificate in the user app so other apps like(outlook, slack, google workspace) can access it and authenticate the user.

I want to install a self-signed certificate (.p12) that will be accessible to all other apps in my system.

I have looked at keystore, CA certificates but those are not helping. Is there any to do this?

Comment: Are you building aosp from sources?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to install certificate programmatically on behalf of a user? Have a look at KeyChain API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain#createInstallIntent(). You can bundle the certificate with your app in assets, then read it at runtime and provide via intent.

Comment: This is a security issue. Why are you doing this.